# Smart pointers as unordered_map key and compare them by reference

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unordered-map

I want to use `unordered_map` to compare elements by reference. I tried to do this by inserting smart pointers as a key (since I do not want to use raw pointers) and implemented `EqualFunction` to compare underlying references of smart pointers. However, the map is not able to find elements correctly.

```
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {};

typedef shared_ptr<Node> NodePtr;

struct HashFunction {
    unsigned long operator()(const NodePtr& key) const {
        return (unsigned long)key.get();
    }
};

struct EqualFunction {
    bool operator()(const NodePtr& t1, const NodePtr& t2) const {
        return t1.get() == t2.get();
    }
};

class Map
{
    unordered_map<NodePtr, int, HashFunction, EqualFunction> map;
public: 
    void insert(NodePtr nodeToInsert, int val)
    {
        map.insert({nodeToInsert, val });
    }

    bool exist(NodePtr node) {
        if (map.find(node) == map.end()) return false;
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node node; Map map;
    auto nodePtr = make_shared<Node>(node);
    map.insert(nodePtr, 1);
    auto ptrToSameNode = make_shared<Node>(node);
    if (map.exist(ptrToSameNode)) 
        cout << "Node exists.";
        else cout << "Node doesn't exist.";
}
```

Above code prints "Node doesn't exist" even through I am searching for the same node.

Comment: You hashes hash incorrectly and the `EqualFunction` is never called. Your `HashFunction ` return different hashes for different objects that should be treated as equivalent. That's a violation of the hashing rule. I think you misunderstand what `std::shared_ptr<T>::get` does. It returns the underlying pointer, not the object

Comment: @Fureeish Hash function is value of underlying row pointer. Hashes are equal if pointers are equals. This is what I need, right?

Comment: No, you don't want that. You want to hash (and compare) objects, not pointers. If you have `auto x = new int(3); auto y = new int(3);` then `x == y` will yield `false`, even though the objecets (allocated `int`s with value `3`) will be equal

Comment: @Fureeish Yes, it will return false because the underlying reference for `x` and `y` are different. This is what I want. I want to compare objects by reference. They should be equal only if they have the same reference wrapped in smart pointer.

Comment: `make_shared<Node>(node)` called twice creates twice a new Node instance, dynamically allocated, by copy-constructing `node`. it's not *wrapping* `node`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, please consider making your comment an answer.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Can you create an answer with the explanation what should be changed in a code in order to have comparison with references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't want to use raw pointers? Use them. Smart pointers are for managing ownership, there are not for pointing to objects created elsewhere.

```
using NodePtr = Node*;

struct HashFunction {
  size_t operator()(const NodePtr& key) const { return (size_t)key; }
};

struct EqualFunction {
  bool operator()(const NodePtr& t1, const NodePtr& t2) const { return t1 == t2; }
};

...

int main()
{
  Node node; Map map;
  auto nodePtr = &node;
  map.insert(nodePtr, 1);
  auto ptrToSameNode = &node;
  if (map.exist(ptrToSameNode)) 
    cout << "Node exists.";
    else cout << "Node doesn't exist.";
}
```

As @Piotr Skotnicki wrote in the comment, the problem was that you originally created 3 `Node` objects, that is, `node` plus 2 dynamically allocated ones that copied `node` (via `make_shared`). Therefore, you then compared (by address) 2 different instances of `Node` class.

---

Alternatively, you can use **shared pointers**, but then you need to create `Node` objects dynamically (not statically on stack as in your code). You can also use **weak pointers** if you don't want your `Map` to "own" the included objects, but then, your comparison will be slower (performed via "locking", i.e., creating shared pointers form weak ones) and there will be a lot of runtime and memory overhead.

Comment: This is not what I want to do. I want one object `Node node`, and multiple pointers pointing to that `node`. Searching for each such pointer in map should return true.

Comment: How I should achieve such behavior in c++. This is default feature when you create dictionary in C# for example. Objects are inserted and compared by reference.

Comment: @Dejan I just updated my answer and deleted previous comments.

Comment: Tnx you the answer. This will work. I just want to make sure that I could not achieve this with the smart pointers (since it is not good to use raw ptrs). Why I cannot create smart pointer which wraps my object reference? I see that `make_shared` doesn't do that, but maybe some other function does.

Comment: @Dejan _"it is not good to use raw ptrs"_ This is completely not true. Using raw pointers is perfectly fine, if you do not care about ownership of pointed-to objects. Over-using smart pointers is bad practice.

Comment: @Dejan see core guideline ["R.3: A raw pointer (a `T*`) is non-owning"](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#r3-a-raw-pointer-a-t-is-non-owning)